# SAS date formatting

Tags: date, input, formatting, sas, put

I have a dataset with a variable, start date, which takes a lot of different values using a character format.

I have split the dataset up using the values in the start date column, because I want to transform the date variable into two new columns with two different date values:

```
if length(Startvalue) = 6 then output  a6;
else if length(Startvalue) = 8 then output a8 ;
else if length(Startvalue) = 1 then output a1;
else output a_other;
```

One value is written like this: 090209 (DDMMYY)

I want to format the variable into both a date9. format and a DDMMYYD10. format like this:

```
FORMAT  Startvalue2 date9.;
format Startvalue3 DDMMYYD10.;
```

I got it to work with this approach in a data step:

```
FORMAT  Startdato2 date9.;
format startdato3 DDMMYYD10.;
Startdato2 = INPUT(PUT(Startdato,6.),DDMMYY6.);
Startdato3 = INPUT(PUT(Startdato,6.),DDMMYY6.);
```

Another value is written like this: 15-08-17 (DD-MM-YY)
I also want the two formats on this value, like this:

```
FORMAT  Startvalue2 date9.;
format Startvalue3 DDMMYYD10.;
```

BUT here I cannot use a copy of my expression from above:

```
FORMAT  Startvalue2 date9.;
format Startvalue3 DDMMYYD10.;
Startvalue2 = INPUT(PUT(Startvalue,8.),DDMMYYDw.);
Startvalue3= INPUT(PUT(Startvalue,8.),DDMMYYDw.);
```

Do you know why? And how I can get the value transformed into a date9. format and a DDMMYYD10 format?

Kind regards

Maria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to convert the values to numeric with a `put` statement when you are using `input`. `input`'s goal is to take a character input and turn it into a numeric value for SAS to do math with. How I always remember it:

- **In**put: Convert an **in**put value **in**to a numeric value
- **Put**: Out**put** a numeric value as a character value

A simpler solution you can try is using the [`anydtdte.` informat](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/64790/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n04jh1fkv5c8zan14fhqcby7jsu4.htm). It is capable of reading any the following informats:

- Date
- Datetime
- DDMMYY
- JULIAN
- MDYAMPM
- MMDDYY
- MMxYY
- MONYY
- TIME
- YMDDTTM
- YYMMDD
- YYQ
- YYxMM
- Month, Day, Year

For example:

```
%let default_datestyle = %sysfunc(getoption(datestyle));

options datestyle=DMY;

data want;
    set have;

    Startdato2  = INPUT(Startdato, anydtdte.);
    Startvalue2 = INPUT(Startvalue, anydtdte.);

    Startdato3  = Startdato2;
    Startvalue3 = Startvalue2;

    <rest of code>;

    format Startvalue2 date9.
           Startvalue3 ddmmyyd10.
           Startdato2  date9.
           Startdato3  ddmmyyd10.
    ;
run;

options datestyle = &default_datestyle;
```

Give that informat a try and see if it is able to get everything. If not, you can account for those special cases with some conditional logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I use this method on the value 21-09-17 I get this output:
17SEP2021 17-09-2021
That's not what I want. It needs to be: 21SEP2017 and 21-09-2017

Comment: From the anydtdte. documentation: "It is possible for input data such as 01-02-03 or 01-02 to be ambiguous with respect to the month, day, and year. In this case, the DATESTYLE system option indicates the order of the month, day, and year." I have updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: Yay, it works! Thanks a lot - not sure I understand the added code, but I accept - and I'm happy :)